# How do i get the mouse position of the location i clicked, on a kinetic.js Stage?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am new to KineticJS and am not being able to get the mouse coordinates of the Stage on `mousedown`. I managed to display the coordinates with `mouseout` and `mouseover` but `mousedown` seems only to work on the **image/shape** that has been added to the Stage, but not the Stage itself.

Can anyone explain to me why is it so? and help me with a solution please.

**[this is the example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/) I tried with:**

---

**Code:**

```
    stage.on('mouseout', function() {
        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
        writeMessage(messageLayer, 'Mouseout triangle:' + mousePos.x);
    });

    stage.on('mouseout','mousemove', function() {

    });

    stage.on('mousedown', function() {
        alert('OK!');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery event listener functions have event params passed in that contain all the information you'll ever need. In this case, you'll maybe want offsetX and offsetY.

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY); 
});
```